# Get third a tag within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click on 3rd a tag and if 3rd a tag is clicked then I want to do few actions. I am trying to select the 3rd a tag by javascript.

I checked other posts within this forum however they only mentioned how to get a single a tag which is inside a td. I appreciate any comment or sample.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group my_first_button">
              <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger my_anchor1">1</a>
              <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary my_anchor2">2</a>
              <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success my_anchor3">3</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the javascript file that I am working on:

```
$('.my_first_button:td a').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.my_first_button .my_anchor3').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

Or use the [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) CSS selector:

```
$('.my_first_button a:nth-child(3)').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`:nth-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) of JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do this with:

```
$('.my_first_button a.my_anchor3').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

if you want to use the `:nth` selector, use this code instead:

```
$('.my_first_button a:nth-child(3)').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

You could also use the `:last` selector, use this:

```
$('.my_first_button a:last').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

Comment: `:td` is not a thing [see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbfue61f/52/)   [check out Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @DelightedD0D Sorry, I forgot to delete the :td part. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use jQuery's [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) :

```
$('.my_first_button a:eq(2)').click(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
    alert($this.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code :

```
$('.my_first_button a:last').click(function(){
    //Some other actions
});
```

Comment: Just keep in mid that this will select the **last** `a` tag, not necessarily the 3rd, depending on context.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

THis will check if the 3rd button was clicked (check by class --not the only way to do it)

```
 $('.my_first_button a').click(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass("my_anchor3")){
    //do your 3rd button stuff
    alert("you click the 3rd btn")
  } else {
    //do other stuff
 }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/55av68r2/)